# Codeigniter : Validating - date not to be longer than two date

Tags: codeigniter

I need resolve this problem:
1) I have in my project two Date input
2) I need the registration(first date) date not to be longer than the date of the tournament(second date).

```
<div class="form-group">
                        <label for="date"><?php echo $lang['date_tournament']; ?></label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control datepicker" name="date_tournament" required>
```

Comment: you can visit this link for your reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14517703/2-date-input-validation-php-with-condition

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php $first = strtotime($registrationdate);
$second = strtotime($tournamentdate);
$datediff = $first  - $second;

if(floor($datediff / (60 * 60 * 24))<2){
echo 'valid';
} ?>
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.  **Flaggers / reviewers:** [For code-only answers such as this one, downvote, don't delete!](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260413/2747593)